# Do you need to obtain a key and save it somewhere once Amazon uses SSE-S3 to encrypt a file?

Tags: amazon-s3

I think I have a fatal misunderstanding of how SSE-S3 encryption works on an Amazon S3 bucket.

I encrypted some of my files and it says the encrypting was successful but I was never given any key to store.

How does SSE-S3 work? Once I enable it on a file, is the accessing of that file any different? It seems to be the same. I'm still able to access the file using its URL in my web browser. I guess the key is stored for me by the bucket and once I access my bucket, any file I want is automatically decrypted? I guess this is to deter people attempting to hack into a bucket and steal all its files?

[This is what I'm seeing on a particular file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKsCg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you need to obtain a key and save it somewhere once Amazon uses SSE-S3 to encrypt a file?

No, the encryption key is fully managed by Amazon S3. The whole encryption and decryption process are taken care of by S3 and you don't need to do anything else besides flipping the switch.

> I encrypted some of my files and it says the encrypting was successful but I was never given any key to store.

Because the key storage is also managed by S3.

> How does SSE-S3 work?

1. You upload a file to S3
2. S3 generates a plain data key  and encrypts it with the S3 master key, so now there are two blobs which correspond to  and `E()`
3. S3 encrypts your file using the plain data key
4. S3 stores your encrypted file and `E()` side by side
5. S3 servers wipe out the plain data key  from the memory

> Once I enable it on a file, is the accessing of that file any different?

No, S3 does all the hard encryption and decryption work for you. You just access the file as normal.

> I guess the key is stored for me by the bucket and once I access my bucket, any file I want is automatically decrypted?

You are right. S3 stores the `E()` for you with your file side-by-side. When you access the file, the underlying data is automatically decrypted.

> I guess this is to deter people attempting to hack into a bucket and steal all its files?

This prevents malicious people with physical access to the hard drives that holds your data from gaining access to the raw bytes of your file.